# recurの引数に関して

Tags: clojure

以下のコード、recurの部分で、期待してる引数の数と違う、とエラーが出ます。
recurの引数は式でなければならないのでしょうか？

```
(defn prime [n]
  (let [result []
        x 2]
    (when (and (zero? (rem n x)) (< x n)))
      (conj result x)
    (recur result (inc x))))
```

Comment: この場合のrecur は、`prime` の呼び出しになるわけですから引数の数が違います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLUEPIXYさんも言われているとおりですが、`recur`の引数の数が違っています。
本来、`recur`は`loop`と共に使われ、`recur`が呼び出されることで制御が(1番内側の)`loop`の位置まで戻ります。

```
(loop [x result [], x 2]
  ...
  (recur (conj result x) (inc x))) ...)
```

関数定義の先頭には、暗黙の`loop`があるものとして扱われるので、対応する`loop`がない場合には`recur`の呼び出しは制御を関数の先頭まで戻します。挙げられている例のコードは以下と等価です：

```
(defn prime [n]
  (loop [n n]
    (let [result []
          x 2]
      (when (and (zero? (rem n x)) (< x n)))
        (conj result x)
      (recur result (inc x)))))
```

ここで、2行目の`loop`と最後の行の`recur`の引数の数が異なるためエラーになります。